# file path getting nil

Tags: ios, filepath

hi to every one i am new to ios

***here is my code***

```
       NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *comicbook_id = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"comicbook_id"];
       NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/book_%@.pdf", documentsDirectory,comicbook_id];



       documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];

       NSLog(@"date==>%@",documentsDirectory);
       ***here i am getting path***
       ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:documentsDirectory password:nil];
      NSLog(@"date==>%@",document); 

*****here i am getting <nil>***** 


       if (document != nil) {

           ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
           readerViewController.delegate = self;
           readerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
           readerViewController.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

           readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
           readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

           [self presentViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: what are you getting at `NSLog(@"date==>%@",documentsDirectory);` ?

Comment: check the file path it should show you "//" before book_x.pdf thats the actual problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this :

```
NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/book_%@.pdf", documentsDirectory,comicbook_id];
```

use

```
 NSString  *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"book_%@.pdf",comicbook_id]];
```

Comment: and i have one more friend" ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];
           readerViewController.delegate = self; readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
           readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;" at getting error readerViewController.delegate = self;

Comment: i did not added any slash berore that here i did like this   NSString *comicbook_id = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"comicbook_id"];
       NSString  *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"book_%@.pdf",comicbook_id]];
       
       NSLog(@"date==>%@",documentsDirectory);

Comment: now i am getting value but at if condition i am getting crash after            ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];

Comment: sorry this is ARC problem

Answer (score 0):

those who are not using ARC and need Reader view controller.please go to the builphases in ur project--->complie sources-->it will list the .m file list please click on which .m which reader have open project, have .m file and double click those one's and write "-fobjc-arc"

automatically reader read's those thanks ya...